# map fields in firestore security rule

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How can i deny all other requests other than the below fields

client code:

```
constructor(private afs:AngularFireStore){}

updateOrder(docId:string){

return this.afs.collection("orderCollection")
.doc(docId)
.update({

updatedOn:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTiimestamp(),

updatedBy:{
uid:currentuser.uid
email:currentuser.email
}

})

}
```

In the incoming request there are two fields.`updatedOn` and `updatedBy`.
The request will be allowed only if the request has only the exact fields `updatedOn` and `updatedBy`.if the request contains fields other than these two field,it will be denied.

The problem is with the `updatedBy` field.It is map field.How can i verify the map field using the security rule?

Here is my security rule

```
 match /orders/{order} {

  allow read, write: if false;
  allow create:if false;

  allow update:if hasOnlyFields(['updatedOn'])
}

function hasOnlyFields(keys) {
 return request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(keys) 
}
```

using the above function i can easily verify the plain field `updatedOn`.But how can verify the map field `updatedBy` using the above function `hasOnlyField`?.If it is not possible with the function `hasOnlyField`, how can i verify the incoming request has only the specified map field and plain field?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish here.  Can you edit the question to clarify what exactly is supposed to be allowed or denied by your rules?  It always helps to show examples of client code that illustrate what should happen in each case.

Comment: question has edited

Comment: What is it about the `updatedBy` field that you actually want to check?  Are you saying that you want to verify that it only has two fields, `uid` and `email`?

Comment: The entire request has only two fields.`updatedOn` and `updatedBy`.Any request other than these two field will be denied.I have to check whether the incoming request has only these two field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to pass any array with all the fields to check:

```
allow update:if hasOnlyFields(['updatedOn', 'updatedBy'])
```

Comment: But `updatedBy` is a map.will it make any problem? let me check

Comment: A field is a field no matter what type of data it contains.  It should be easy to test for yourself.

Comment: But `updatedBy` contains two more fields,does that make any problem.?

Comment: No.  I suggest trying it for yourself - it should be easy to test.